# A Question about Variational Calculus when F= y-y'

Tags: exponential-function, calculus-of-variations

I am having trouble with F = y - y'

If I set F = |y - y'| and

do $\int F(y,y') dx$,

it seems obvious that $y=\exp(x)$ should be extremal

since $F=|\exp(x)-\frac{d \exp(x)}{dx}| = |\exp(x)-\exp(x)|=0$

But I am not sure how to apply Euler-Lagrange Equation...

Is this any way to solve generalization of this problem?

Comment: Are the end points fixed?

Comment: yes, I presume... for this problem, y(0)=1, y(1)=exp(1)... Even in this trivial situation, will there be a path to solution? and what if we assume general end points? so yes... general endpoints or fixed endpoints

Comment: To apply E-L equation, the function $F$ need to be differentiable, it is not in your example. If you could change to $|y-y'|^2$ it were better.